# RESTFul Web Service type of framework on top of Http calls

Tags: java, http, url, rest

We have a system wherein numerous retrieval/updation operations can be performed using making http calls. Now, am wondering if it would make sense to write a Web Service framework on top of these HTTP calls so that would reduce the effort on the client end and also the duplication of code is removed. Is this a scenario for having a RESTful Service type of framework in place. If yes, please point to me how and additional benefits it could provide and if not why not?
Would highly appreciate if anyone provides recommendations around the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it sounds like a good case for a RESTful interface.  In my mind anytime your problem that requires classic CRUD actions, then its a good candidate for a restful interface.  As you pointed out the benefits for the client side are ease of use, but I find that developing restful interfaces really brings out good thought processes for designing your system in general.  Its easier to spot hidden domain models and really delve deeper into your applications concepts in my opinion.

There are some decent articles on Oracles site for implementing restful interfaces through java like:

http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/jax-rs/index.html

If you haven't read Roy Fielding's disseration, its a must read:

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm